# Parse::RecDescent does it only operate on a string?

Tags: perl

I was looking at using [Parse::RecDescent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::RecDescent) to parse some large files. I was figuring I'd pass it a token at a time. After looking at it a while, it appears that the tokenizer is built into it and you have to pass it the whole string up front. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You normally pass the complete text to be parsed as a string.

However, note that it's documented that if you pass the text as a reference:

```
$parser->startrule(\$text);
```

then the matched portion of `$text` will be removed, leaving only what did not match.  It may be possible to design your grammar so that you can parse a file in chunks.

Comment: Hmm,  so every time an EOL is hit add a little more to the string